# Unable to get the receive messages in chat screen in xmpp

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

I am making an app based on chatting i am able to send the messages but unable to recieve messages in my chat screen so can any body help me out
here is my code

```
if ([[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue]==nil) {

}
else
{

    NSString *messageBody = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[message from]
                                                             xmppStream:xmppStream
                                                   managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext_roster]];
    NSString *displayName = [user displayName];
    BOOL isComposing = NO;

    NSString *MyString;
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm,yyyy/MM/dd"];
    MyString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    NSLog(@"TIME AND DATE=>%@",MyString);

    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *myJID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@xxxx-mac-mini-2.local",[defaults valueForKey:@"userNameJID"]];
    NSString *friendID=[[[message attributeForName:@"from"] stringValue] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
      NSLog(@"---chatToUserId=>%@",friendID);




     if ([message isChatMessageWithBody]){

        XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[message from]
                                                                 xmppStream:xmppStream
                                                       managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext_roster]];

        NSString *body = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
        NSString *displayName = [user displayName];
        NSString *msg = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
        NSString *from = [[message attributeForName:@"from"] stringValue];

        //  [xmppMessageArchivingStorage archiveMessage:message outgoing:NO  xmppStream:xmppStream];



        NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [m setObject:msg forKey:@"msg"];
        [m setObject:from forKey:@"sender"];}
```

in xmpp delegate method that is didReceiveMessage but how can i assign to chat screen class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn:

1. `XMPPMessageArchiving` is an example module bundled with `XMPPFramework` which store all incoming and outgoing messages to CoreData-backed database.
2. `NSFetchedResultsController` - standard Apple-provided class for feeding data to `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`, which you can use as core of "chat screen" class and it will automatically track new messages and update UI.

Sample `iPhoneXMPP` project have an example of "roster screen" which is backed by UITableView and NSFRC, the only two differences of "chat screen" are:

1. You need to fetch `XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject` entities
2. You need to specify `NSPredicate` to fetch only messages related to single "chat", something like `bareJid == %@` and pass buddy's JID to this predicate

Comment: thanks for the replay i am able to receive the message but not showing in tableview chat screen and i am using sqlite database for storing i am inserting send/receive messages. for fetching i am using nspredicate  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subscription=='both'"];

Comment: Your code is attempt to reinvent XMPPMessageArchiving module, try to see its code and understand how it works